# How do you remove time component from a timestamp?

Tags: sql, vertica, vsql

How do you remove the time component from a timestamp for instance:

```
2014-01-01 12:00:01
```

To become

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: your title is somewhat confusing. do you actually want to remove the timestamp piece entirely so that you'd have a simple date - 2014-01-01' or do you actually want to reset it to 00:00:00

Comment: just reset to 00:00:00.

Comment: I would highly encourage going through the documentation before asking a question. See [this](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I did try the doc but I obviously missed it. Googling didn't help much either and that's why the ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're actually asking how to remove the **time** component from a `timestamp` type.

Let's set up some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    time_stamp timestamp
);

INSERT INTO public.test (time_stamp) VALUES (SYSDATE());
INSERT INTO public.test (time_stamp) VALUES (SYSDATE());
INSERT INTO public.test (time_stamp) VALUES (SYSDATE());
COMMIT;
```

Before the transformation, the data looks like:

```
         time_stamp
----------------------------
 2014-07-01 21:37:11.454081
 2014-07-01 21:37:15.521172
 2014-07-01 21:37:18.048398
```

We'll use the [`TRUNC`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/TRUNCDateTime.htm) function to truncate the value:

```
SELECT TRUNC(time_stamp, 'dd') FROM public.test;
```

This produces:

```
        TRUNC
---------------------
 2014-07-01 00:00:00
 2014-07-01 00:00:00
 2014-07-01 00:00:00
```

If you prefer to write it out:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(time_stamp AS date) AS timestamp) FROM public.test;
```

Or

```
SELECT time_stamp::date::timestamp FROM public.test;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you know the actual difference that you want to reset you can use the timestampadd. For your example, you would need to do this twice:

```
select timestampadd(ss, -1, (timestampadd(hh, -12, '2014-01-01 12:00:01')))
```

this is the link to the vertica documentation on how to use timestampadd:
https://my.vertica.com/docs/5.0/HTML/Master/16090.htm

Comment: So if there are hr, min and sec, does it mean I have to do it three times? Doesn't sound very efficient to me...